# hspace except at the beginning of a line

Tags: spacing, footnotes, footmisc

I am using the `footmisc` package:

```
\usepackage[perpage,para]{footmisc}
```

Every time I make a footnote, I use my own `podnote` command:

```
\newcommand{\podnote}[1]{\footnote{\hspace{-1ex}#1}}
```

However, I do not actually want there to be space at the beginning of a line:
[image: example]

How do I keep the spaces which are circled green and get rid of the one which is crossed out in red? (I don't know that this is relevant, but I am using XeLaTeX.)

Comment: How about you produce a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that interested parties (us!) can play around with it?

Comment: irrelevant niggle -- `ex` should really be used only for vertical dimensions; better to use `em` (here, perhaps `.3em` for horizontal ones.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's good to know. Just curious, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @karzak The TeX Book p. 60 is one.  But the recommendation is more of a conceptual one rather than substantive.  Both `ex` and `em` are font-dependent measures, and either one will work.

Comment: @Alan's right, of course, about this being conceptual, but if you're using fonts other than computer modern (where all styles have essentially the same proportions), you might get a surprise switching, say, from serif to sans.

Comment: @Werner This is very strange, but I am having trouble getting an example which is minimal which is displaying this problem. More later if I get it working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem.  Here's a minimal example which patches the footnote text code to remove the space (rather than adding a negative space in each footnote.)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[perpage,para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{.5em}{0em}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

This is some text.\footnote{A footnote that has a few lines. More. Line. More. .More}
Some text\footnote{This is longer. It is longer.} This\footnote{Another one that.}
is some more text.\footnote{Another footnote that has some more lines.} Some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This is a good corrective of my hack. However, strangely enough, it hasn't fixed my problem! See my comment about about the MWE.

Comment: So add packages from your actual document gradually to this example to see what's causing the interaction.

Comment: Incredibly strange...returning to my document after several months, I have somehow unintentionally fixed the problem (either that, or it is not appearing anymore randomly). Anyway, I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer.