# footmisc effects with endnotes

Tags: endnotes, footmisc

I want my endnotes to simulate the effect of

```
\usepackage[para,norule,hang]{footmisc}
```

With these settings, footnotes occur within a single paragraph.  Each endnote, by contrast, begins on a new line.  I've added some code (from Alan Munn, re [hspace except at the beginning of a line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38057/2693)) to kill the indent, but can't figure out how to replace with the carriage carry with the same horizontal spacing as `footmisc` places between the footnotes.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[para,norule,hang]{footmisc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{.5em}{0em}{}{}
\makeatother

%KILL ENDNOTE INDENT 
   %\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt \leftskip=0pt \parindent=0em \leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}
\patchcmd{\enoteformat}{1.8em}{0pt}{}{}

\begin{document}

Gallia\footnote{in} est\footnote{one} omnis\footnote{paragraph}
divisa\endnote{in} in\endnote{a} partes\endnote{vertical} tres\endnote{list}

\newpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you need to patch a more substantial piece of code, so I don't think it's so easily done with a `patchcmd`.  Here's a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[para,norule,hang]{footmisc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{.5em}{0em}{}{}
\def\theendnotes{\immediate\closeout\@enotes \global\@enotesopenfalse
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \edef\@tempa{`\string >}%
    \ifnum\catcode\@tempa=12%
      \let\@ResetGT\relax
    \else
      \edef\@ResetGT{\noexpand\catcode\@tempa=\the\catcode\@tempa}%
      \@makeother\>%
    \fi
    \def\@doanenote##1##2>{\def\@theenmark{##1}\begingroup
        \@ResetGT
        \edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@endnote\endcsname\@theenmark}%
        \enoteformat}
    \def\@endanenote{\hspace{1em}\endgroup}%
    \enoteheading
    \enotesize
    \input{\jobname.ent}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
%KILL ENDNOTE INDENT
\patchcmd{\enoteformat}{1.8em}{0pt}{}{}
\begin{document}

Gallia\footnote{in} est\footnote{one} omnis\footnote{paragraph}
divisa\endnote{in} in\endnote{a} partes\endnote{vertical} tres\endnote{list}

\newpage

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly.  Off to inspect the code.  (Apologies for the misattribution of code.  I've edited the question.)

Comment: All I did was remove two `\par` commands from the code and replaced one with an `\hspace`.